# NextJS - Not able to get cookie in route.ts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, cookies

I am using NextJS App Router.
When I try to get `token` from cookies in my api route, it returns nothing.

/app/api/profile/route.ts

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

const getCookie = async (name: string) => {
 return cookies().get(name)?.value ?? "";
};

export async function GET(request) {
 const token = await getCookie("accessToken");  
 console.log(token); // I can't log the token here
 return NextResponse.json(user.data, { status: 200 });
}
```

layout.tsx

```
const test123 = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/profile");
```

However, when I do the same in `layout.ts`, it works.

layout.tsx

```
...
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

const getCookie = async (name: string) => {
 return cookies().get(name)?.value ?? "";
};

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
 const token = await getCookie("accessToken");
 console.log(token) // I can successfully log the token here!

 return (
   ...
  );
}
```

How to fix it?

**Update 1**
I set the cookies from my NestJS backend when it sends the response to my NextJS frontend, if that matters

```
  async login(@Body() loginDto: LoginDto, @Response() res: ExpressResponse) {
    const loginRes = await this.authService.login(loginDto.token);

    res.cookie('accessToken', loginRes?.accessToken, {
      expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000), // 1 hr
      sameSite: 'strict',
      httpOnly: true,
    });

    return res.send(loginRes);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the docs claim to allow you access to cookies and setting cookies in a route handler.  [Here on the app router docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#cookies) this is how they claim to do it.

[image: Nextjs Docs]

I just tested this on my app and can console.log the value in in my route.ts route handler.  I tested your code structure and it works as well.  Maybe check you are using the correct string identifier for the cookie you are trying to access.

```
const getCookie = async (name: string) => {
const cookieStore = cookies();
return cookieStore.get(name)?.value ?? '';
};

export async function GET(
  req: Request,
  { params }: { params: { id: string } }
) {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  console.log(cookieStore.get('authjs.session-token'));
  console.log(await getCookie('authjs.session-token'));
}
```

It returned my cookie value for both of the logs.

Comment: I tried to set the cookie in NextJS as told by the doc, but I couldn't find it in browser inspector

Comment: That should definitely be the problem then, my inspector shows my cookies in the browser.  I am using nextauth.js (now changing to  just auth.js) with their built in providers for my authentication.  I have not tried to manually manipulate the cookies yet.